# Member class declare order Android

Tags: android, naming-conventions, declare

How to order right class members if I have:

```
public static final Const;//Constants
@Inject//Some injections
@BindView//Some butterknife binds
private Object object;//Just objects
private int number;//Primitives
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usualy @Inject and @BindView is on top
then constants objects and primitivs